# How to (un)dock IBM Thinkpad X41 from X4 Dock(ing station) successfully?

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, thinkpad, docking

I'd like to start using my docking station again; however, it still doesn't work as it should, see the following bug descriptions (with special focus on [**Thinkpad X41**](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aX41) & the [**X4 Dock**](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_X4_Dock)). Given that it still doesn't work (effective April 2012), my hope is fading that it will start working all of a sudden with Precise Pangolin at the end of the month. This issue is VERY important to me and I would be MOST grateful to anyone being able to sieve through **the following links** (some of which are actually quite recent) and translate their meaning into reliable and concrete simple (?) steps. I've read briefly about **hal** and **udev**, and can imagine that they are somewhat related to this, see links below. I don't want to fire at random. I don't want to tinker around with bash scripts if avoidable...

**Problem description** (more or less ;-)

> [*Pressing the undock button on a "**ThinkPad X4 Dock**" with a **ThinkPad X40** does not
>   cause any udev events. And the lights on the dock never change to indicate it
>   is safe to undock.*](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15521)

and

> [***IBM Thinkpad X41*** & **docking station** >> no joy :-( ... when pressing the blue undock button on the docking station:
>    - The screen goes blank (with backlight remaining on),
>    - with some SSD/HDD activity;
>    - ctrl alt del causes a shut down after ... seconds, indicating that the system itself hasn't "crashed" but is still (somewhat ?)
>   responsive.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/691272)

and

> [*With **recent** distributions, **docking** and **undocking** should function **out of the box**. You can monitor this by running **# udevadm monitor** and when you dock or press the undock button you should see a flurry of events. There are some issues though: **No event on undock**. - In some cases you may **not** get **any** events on
>   undock. This is due to the ACPI dock drivers only registering the
>   first logical Dock port they encounter and **in some rare cases** there
>   may be more then one, **such as** on a **ThinkPad X40** with **ThinkPad X4 Dock**.
>   Patches are available, and are merged in
>   2.6.34.*](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Docking_Solutions#No_event_on_undock)

Now, if patches are available and merged into 2.6.34 - why isn't (un)docking simply working / fully supported in the latest version of Natty (which to my humble understanding has surpassed kernel version 2.6.34 a while ago)?

More relevant links:

> [***ThinkPad X41 Docking Station***
>   issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1773828)

and

> [***[HOWTO] Run scripts*** for laptop lid open/close and **dock/undock
>   events**](http://ubuntuforums.org/printthread.php?t=1076486&pp=75)

and finally

> [*Symptoms corrected by the latest BIOS Update - ThinkPad X41 - (Fix) USB devices connected to UltraBase X4 or **ThinkPad X4 Dock** may
>   not be recognized in Boot Menu by pressing F12 during
>   POST.*](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-59720)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *preliminary*, but pending further findings I think this issue has been resolved by means of normal updates: it seems to be working just fine now (using the `blue undock button on the docking station` when undocking; and cycling through `fn f7` if using an external monitor), hot-warm-lukewarm docking all seems to be handled well now.

Thanks, UBUNTU !

UPDATE:
even after (accidentally) undocking (while a lot of stuff was running) ***without*** pressing the `blue undock button on the docking station` the system remained stable / responsive / "there" / reliable / etc (only a quick "toggle" of `fn f7` needed to get the display(s) back in order). So, finally, **it just works !!** yeah :D